# PayPal Sandbox 400 error after redirection

Tags: laravel, paypal

i use laravel V6

```
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
            'token..',
            'token..'
        )
    );

   //dd($transaction);
    $callbackUrl = url('/paypal/status');

    $payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    $amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
    $amount->setTotal('1.00');
    $amount->setCurrency('USD');

    $transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);

    $redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($callbackUrl)
        ->setCancelUrl($callbackUrl);

    $payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

    try {
        $payment->create($apiContext);
        //dd($payment);
        //dd($payment->getApprovalLink());
        return redirect()->away($payment->getApprovalLink());
    } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
        var_dump(json_decode($ex->getData()));
        exit(1);
    }
```

that's the controller, I followed the documentation [enter link description here](http://%20https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)
but I get a 400 error [enter link description here](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/checkout/EC-88M93704JL735000S/session/create)
The link it generates is as follows https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?flow=1-P&ulReturn=true&token=EC-88M93704JL735000S&country.x=US&locale.x=es_XC#/checkout/genericError?code=UEFZTUVOVF9ERU5JRUQ%3D

I can not understand why the error .. the client_id secret, are fine .. anyway it is directly in the controller and check that the sandbox account has a balance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that ClientId/Secret it looks like the receiving account in the PayPal sandbox is from a country that cannot receive any payments, such as Bolivia. Create a new sandbox business account at https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F for a different country that is able to receive PayPal payments, and then create a REST app for this new sandbox business account in the 'My Applications' side tab.

---

It looks like you are using an obsolete PHP integration, with the old v1 payments SDK

You should instead use the v2 Checkout-PHP-SDK, with two routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Instead of redirecting to the approval URL, use this front-end UI: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server -- this gives an "in context" checkout experience that keeps your site loaded in the background, which provides a much superior modern web experience